# OpenCV, cover contour with rectangles

Tags: python, opencv, contour

how is it possible with OpenCV to cover an irregular shape with multiple rectangles? See example figurs.

The rectangles should be covering max area of the object and can be in any angles. It is important that they do not overlap each other. If rectangle is covering some of the background, it is perfectly OK.

I have found this [thread](https://answers.opencv.org/question/25912/split-contours-into-many-small-rectangles/) who split contours into small rectangles, but they do not merge into biggest rectangle possible. [https://answers.opencv.org/question/25912/split-contours-into-many-small-rectangles/]

I do use OpenCV with python, but if you have example code in C++ it is completely fine.

[Before image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBFrB.png)

[Wanted result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68tlg.png)

Comment: Get the 1 inner and 1 outer contours from the white area. Then get the bounding rectangles of each contour (w,h,x,y). From that you can compute the thickness of the white region and then draw rectangles as you desired using the thickness and the x,y of the upper left corners of each bounding box. See cv2.findContours() and cv2.cv2.boundingRect() in the OpenCV documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one simple way to break this up into 4 rectangles using Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Convert to gray
- Threshold
- Get the two contours
- Compute two vertical lines the length of the outer (larger) contour height, but along the sides of the inner (smaller) contour
- Draw these vertical lines on the thresholded image
- Get and draw the contours on the previous image
- Save the result

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('rectangles.png')
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# get contours and get the largest and smallest ones
contour_img = img.copy()
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
min_area_thresh = hh * ww
max_area_thresh = 0
for cntr in contours:
    cv2.drawContours(contour_img, [cntr], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
    area = cv2.contourArea(cntr)
    if area < min_area_thresh:
        xs,ys,ws,hs = cv2.boundingRect(cntr)
        min_area_thresh = area
        small_contour = cntr
    if area > max_area_thresh:
        xl,yl,wl,hl = cv2.boundingRect(cntr)
        max_area_thresh = area
        large_contour = cntr


# compute vertical lines of height of large contour along the sides of the inner contours
x1 = xs
y1 = yl
x2 = x1
y2 = yl + hl - 1
x3 = xs + ws - 1
y3 = yl
x4 = x3
y4 = y2

# draw two vertical lines in black on thresholded image to separate segments
thresh2 = thresh.copy()
cv2.line(thresh2, (x1,y1), (x2,y2), 0, 1) 
cv2.line(thresh2, (x3,y3), (x4,y4), 0, 1) 

# get and draw contours from thresh2
result = thresh2.copy()
result = cv2.merge([result,result,result])
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh2, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
for cntr in contours:
    color = list(np.random.random(size=3) * 256)
    cv2.drawContours(result, [cntr], -1, color, 2)

# show thresh and result    
cv2.imshow("input", img)
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("contours", contour_img)
cv2.imshow("thresh2", thresh2)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# save resulting images
cv2.imwrite('rectangles_contours.png',contour_img)
cv2.imwrite('rectangles_thresh2.png',thresh2)
cv2.imwrite('rectangles_result.png',result)
```

Large and small contours on thresholded image:

[image]

Two black vertical lines drawn on thresholded image:

[image]

Random color contours drawn on previous image as result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!

A bit more extra to make it fit angles, but that I do know how to fix.